# Get maxDate from datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use datetimepicker from this [Bootstrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals).

I using option maxDate option, like this :

```
'maxDate' => new Date().setHours("23")
```

I see in code in inspect element, this option has successfully generate.

```
<input type="text" id="booking-date_end_booking" class="form-control" name="Booking[date_end_booking]" aria-required="true" maxdate="24-07-2017 23:00">
```

Now, how to get those attribute. It always give me `undefined`, if I use common command in jQuery to get it's attribute.

```
alert($('#booking-date_end_booking').attr('maxDate'));
```

I need this because I want to override this attribute using ajax response.

```
$('#booking-date_end_booking').attr('maxdate', response.tanggalEnd);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to set/get the **maxDate** option value you can use the function [maxDate()](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate):

For getting the current value:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate();
```

For setting a new value:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(moment('01/08/2017 23:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
```

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    maxDate: new Date().setHours("23")
});

var x = $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate();
console.log('maxDate is: ' + x.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'))


$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(moment('01/08/2017 23:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));

x = $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate();
console.log('new maxDate is: ' + x.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'))
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type="text" id="booking-date_end_booking" class="form-control"
                           name="Booking[date_end_booking]" aria-required="true">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```